# How do I vertically align radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment

so I want to have a sheet with an question and five radio buttons. But as you can see, with different question lengths it is quite a mess. How do I align the buttons nicely so that they are vertically under the header despite the length of the question?

[IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/vpkftw.png[/IMG]

This is the html:

```
<h4> Ans1  </h4><h4>Answer2 </h4><h4> Ans3 </h4><h4> Ans4 </h4><h4>Ans5 </h4> <br>
Q1 ......................      <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_1" value="1"> <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_2" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_3" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_4" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v1" id="v1_5" value="Bike"> <br>
Q2... <input type="radio" name="v2" id="v2_1" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v2" id="v2_2" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v2" id="v2_3"value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v2" id="v2_4" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v2" id="v2_5" value="Bike"> <br>
Q3.<input type="radio" name="v3" id="v3_1" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v3" id="v3_2" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v3" id="v3_3"value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v2" id="v3_4" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v2" id="v3_5" value="Bike"> <br>
Q4 <input type="radio" name="v4" id="v4_1" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v4" id="v4_2" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v4" id="v4_3"value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v4" id="v4_4" value="Bike"> <input type="radio" name="v4" id="v4_5" value="Bike"> <br>
```

CSS:

```
h4 {
display: inline;
position: relative;
left: 280px;

}

h4:nth-child(2) {
margin-left:6em;

}


h4:nth-child(3) {
margin-left:5em;


}


h4:nth-child(4) {
margin-left:7em;

}

h4:nth-child(5) {
margin-left:4em;

}
```

Comment: Why not use tables?

Comment: @Hektor because I dont want lines between the questions, that makes it a bit ugly in my opinion

Comment: It would help if you recreate the issue in jsfiddle or codepen so we can see exactly whats happening.

Comment: 1. Its bad practice to use tables for layout purposes. 2. If you do need to use tables for displaying actual tabular data, they can be styled any way you like - without lines etc

Comment: your image link isn't working and your code looks like this https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/OjmJrV I don't know what you're trying to vertically align exactly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/75x9j9Lv/

Comment: @MichaelCoker I want the radiobuttons to be vertically aligned

Comment: vertically aligned with what?

Comment: each other, so the buttons of ans1 stands beneath eachother, and ans2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put your html within a table like you see in here there is no border, line or whatever. But if so, just remove it with `border:0px;` for example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMmydy

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>50</td>
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>50</td>
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
</table>
```